# Can't generate java files in eclipse from wsdl and xsd files

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, xsd, wsdl

I'm trying to generate java classes from wsdl and xsd files in Eclipse so I found this command `wsimport -keep -b schema/current/AXLSOAP.xsd -Xnocompile  -s src -d bin -verbose schema/current/AXLAPI.wsdl` but I'm running a windows 10 OS.
So what's the equivalent command in windows?

Answer (score 0):

`wsimport` is part of the JDK installation.